# Exit code from ClickOnce application installation

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I found couple ways of running `.application` ClickOnce file. One can be to simply run this file as an executable (and let explorer do the rest) or run it as explorer does using `rundll32.exe`.

The thing is that I want to wait until this ClickOnce application finished installation. Waiting for exit code from `Start-Process \path\to\file.application -Wait` doesn't make sense because the ClickOnce app runs as a different process named `dfsvc.exe`. Thing is that this process  usually runs in a background and does not exit after installation is complete so I can't just simply wait until it appears and then wait until it exits.

How can I programmatically check that the ClickOnce app finished installing?

Comment: What, specifically, do you want to do once that app is launched? Can you just add it to the start-up of your executable?

Comment: Not once it's launched but after it's installed. I'm making a program(script) which installs bunch of different apps in a row but it should not install App2 when App1 is not installed. One of those apps is ClickOnce app and since it returns exit code immediatelly, some app2 begins installation even though app1 (clickonce) did not finish its installation.

Comment: Is there Any solution to this Problem or any link we can look for its solution

Answer (score 1):

Mike,

If I understand your situation, you have several applications, one of which is a ClickOnce application, and you would like these applications to install synchronously, with each application installing fully before proceeding to the next one.

I've run into a similar situation on a few occasions with ClickOnce and have verified the installation completes with something like the below:

I select some files installed as part of the ClickOnce installation process, and check for their existence before continuing with the next application in the synchronous lineup. Usually this is done through some overarching install script or exe to monitor the install of each successive application. I'll often use a loop, checking and pausing before installing the next program in the lineup. Below is some sample code to give you an idea of what I mean:

```
int fileFolderCount = 0;
while (fileFolderCount != beforeInstallCount.Count() || Process.GetProcessesByName("ExeToInstall").Length != 0) 
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    fileFolderCount = new DirectoryInfo(clickOnceFilesDir)
        .GetFiles("regExpToFindClickOnceFiles", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Count()        // this will recurse through the clickOnceFilesDir and pull files that match the regExpToFindClickOnceFiles. Ideally these will be the files I'm looking for as part of the install.
}
```

Once the install has completed, the files will be present, satisfying the first part of the loop condition, and the second condition is for those applications set to run upon install, so that they can be closed before proceeding with the next application in line for installation.

HTH